# Moveit move_group_interface freezes after planning towards current pose

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When planning towards a pose goal with move_group_interface, my program freezes. The goal was successfully planned, there is no error message:

```
[ INFO] [1468585702.343711063]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[ INFO] [1468585702.346383724]: No planner specified. Using default.
[ INFO] [1468585702.347143174]: RRTConnect: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1468585702.386972714]: RRTConnect: Created 4 states (2 start + 2 goal)
[ INFO] [1468585702.387030791]: Solution found in 0.040406 seconds
[ INFO] [1468585702.394637573]: SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.001726 seconds and changed from 3 to 2 states
```

After the last message, the program freezes.

To plan the pose goal, I used the following code:

```
this->move_group_interface->setPoseTarget(this->move_group_interface->getCurrentPose(this->move_group_interface->getEndEffectorLink()), this->move_group_interface->getEndEffectorLink());
```

I cannot imagine, why the `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::plan()` should block my program even after the plan was successfully created.

Thank you for your help!

---

**Update:** The same behaviour is observed for  `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::move()` after setting a pose goal and a (valid) position near the current position:

```
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose_s = this->move_group_interface->getCurrentPose(this->move_group_interface->getEndEffectorLink());
pose_s.pose.position.x += 0.1;
this->move_group_interface->setPoseTarget(pose_s, this->move_group_interface->getEndEffectorLink());
moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode success = this->move_group_interface->move();
```

Program output looks similar (only addition is, the robot in RVIZ is moved to show the calculating path. Then, my program freezes, like before):

```
[ INFO] [1468846527.748218369]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[ INFO] [1468846527.748530839]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1468846527.751398850]: No planner specified. Using default.
[ INFO] [1468846527.752396733]: RRTConnect: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1468846527.795039078]: RRTConnect: Created 5 states (3 start + 2 goal)
[ INFO] [1468846527.795096722]: Solution found in 0.043326 seconds
[ INFO] [1468846527.808806888]: SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.000047 seconds and changed from 4 to 2 states
[ INFO] [1468846527.813859153]: Fake execution of trajectory
```

The robot is moved. The `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::move()` function also blocks my code forever.
Seems like it waits for the (non-existent, as I do not use fake execution) action server for an unlimited amount of time to respond. Gdb shows that the program freezes here:

```
Single stepping until exit from function _ZNK3ros10NodeHandle2okEv,
which has no line number information.
0x00007f90874c33a7 in actionlib::SimpleActionClient<moveit_msgs::MoveGroupAction_<std::allocator<void> > >::waitForResult(ros::Duration const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libmoveit_move_group_interface.so
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239583/moveit-move_group_interface-freezes-after-planning-towards-current-pose/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-18**:
Could it be that MoveIt is not receiving any joint state msgs / updates, and thus cannot properly track the state of execution of your trajectory? Hanging in `waitForResult(..)` and your comment "*the robot is moved*" seem to point in that direction.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2016-08-16**:
Sorry for my late answer, but this can't be the case, because when I move the robot using joint space, RVIZ follows properly.
Also the robot is not moving, just the RVIZ sim shows the 'preview' of the computed path, then my program freezes because of move_group_interface. updated description on this

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2016-08-16**:
Could it be that something cannot be initialized? (Referring to: [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/s9b7IJuKRKY))
I call `plan` in my main loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to put the whole loop that calls move_groupe_interface's `plan` function in a new thread for it to return.

(I followed the [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/s9b7IJuKRKY) discussion and, as stated there, disattached the call to `plan` from my main loop)

---

Originally posted by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) with karma: 200 on 2016-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3